# HTML entities are not being decoded when using WordPress REST API for Gutenberg blocks

Tags: wordpress, rest, block, html-entities, wordpress-gutenberg

I am building a custom Gutenberg block that makes a request to the WordPress REST API to get some Posts. I'm using `axios` to make the request to the REST endpoint.

When the result comes back, there is an array of Post objects, and I can see the titles of the Posts, but they are all contained in the JSON object as `title.rendered` and contain HTML entities eg.

```
title: {
    rendered: "This has a hyphen &#8211; oh dear"
}`
```

I'm trying to populate a `<SelectControl>` with the resulting data, so there's no way to use the React `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method which would solve the entities problem. So how can I get rid of these entities when populating the options?

Here is the code I'm using to populate the options from the REST response:

```
const options = response.data.map((post) => {
    return {
        label: post.title.rendered,
        value: post.id,
    };
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious, but there is in fact a method made available in the Blocks API to do this.

At the top of your block code, type:

```
const { decodeEntities } = wp.htmlEntities;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
const options = response.data.map((post) => {
    return {
        label: decodeEntities(post.title.rendered),
        value: post.id,
    };
});
```

Bazoozaa! HTML entities are gone.

Comment: in my case, I added this line:

`import {decodeEntities} from "@wordpress/html-entities";`

after run 
`npm install @wordpress/html-entities --save`

Comment: Yep - that works perfectly if you're using the @wordpress imports (I'm using that too) - I'll add that into the answer

Answer (score 4):

And why not using [`rest_prepare_<post_type>`](http://hookr.io/4.7.4/filters/rest_prepare_post_type/) filter ?

```php
$post_type = "post";
add_filter( "rest_prepare_{$post_type}", 'prefix_title_entity_decode' );
function prefix_title_entity_decode( $response ) {
    $data = $response->get_data();
    $data['title']['rendered'] = html_entity_decode( $data['title']['rendered'] );
    $response->set_data( $data );
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: You should also pass new title value through `wp_kses_post()`, because it may contain unescaped tags that might lead to XSS vulnerabilities: ```$data['title']['rendered'] = wp_kses_post( html_entity_decode( $data['title']['rendered'] ) );```